# Missing number, treated as zero. When attempting define special characters

Tags: errors

Looking into multiple threads, I stil cannot seem to solve my error. I therefore hope some of you might be able to help me out?

When attempting to define the three scandinavian letters å æ ø Å Æ Ø with the following code:

```
\catcode`æ=\active\catcode`ø=\active\catcode`å=\active
\catcode`Æ=\active\catcode`Ø=\active\catcode`Å=\active
\defæ{\ae}\defø{\o}\defå{\aa}
\defÆ{\AE}\defØ{\O}\defÅ{\AA}
```

I get the following error message when I typeset the document:

```
./main.tex:63: Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
```

I am using "Classicthesis" and the input is defined as latin9

Hope one of you will be able to help me out here!

Best regards,
Henrik

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Not knowing what code may be on line 63 of `main.tex`, it's hard to provide a clean diagnosis, let alone suggest a cure. Incidentally, since you would appear to have a keyboard that lets you enter the "Scandinavian" characters (`æ`, `Æ`, etc) directly, why not just load the `inputenc` and `fontenc` packages with the appropriate options and enter the characters along with the "non-Scandinavian" characters? Put differently, why are you making them into macros?

Comment: You don't say which engine (pdfTeX/XeTeX/LuaTeX) you are using: this is important here as what you have above will only work in XeTeX and LuaTeX, not in pdfTeX.

Comment: What's the purpose of doing that? If your file is Latin-9 encoded, just add `\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}` to your preamble and LaTeX will do everything for you.

Answer (score 4):

I can reproduce the issue, but only if the input file is UTF-8. If I save it as Latin-9, the definitions are performed without any complaint.

Why is the error issued when the file is encoded as UTF-8? Because in this case what you see as `æ` is actually *two* characters, as far as TeX is concerned (it doesn't understand multibyte encodings). Precisely, `æ` is seen as the pair of bytes `<C3><A6>`, so what TeX really sees is

```
\catcode`<C3><A6>=\active
```

(note that `<xy>` is used just to represent a single character), which is a bad assignment and indeed will trigger the error message you see. This *cannot* happen if the file is encoded in a one byte encoding such as Latin-9.

In any case you *shouldn't* do things like that. Check the file encoding looking carefully to what your text editing program tells you and then add to the document preamble

```
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
```

if the encoding really turns out to be Latin-9, or

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

if instead it is UTF-8. Both declarations (when the option agrees with the encoding of the file) automatically do what you want to do manually.

<sub>I'm under the impression that you're using some template you got from the net or some friend. Don't trust them, particularly if they contain things you know absolutely nothing about.</sub>